# How can I change the counter to return the date

Tags: php

Can you tell me how I can make the following script generate:
2015000001
2015000002

instead of:
1
2
3

It should also recognize the year it should use itself. So this would change to 2016 next year for example.

```
 //Define the key to store in the database
 define( 'CF7_COUNTER', 'cf7-counter' );

 //Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
 function cf7dtx_counter(){
     $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;  //Increment the current count
     return $val;
  }
  add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

  //Action performed when the mail is actually sent by CF7
  function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
      $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
      update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count
  }
  add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Amro

Comment: You need database connectivity for this. Store the last ticketnumber issued in db, then everytime you add `1` to column, you update the ticketnumbercount by 1

Comment: You can use the PHP `date` function to get yearmonthday. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php You should use a DB for the ticket numbers, random ticket numbers aren't good because they could overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows . Just add `date` function.

```
  $value = ("Y-m-d");

        //Create the shortcode which will set the value for the DTX field
         function cf7dtx_counter(){
         $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1;  //Increment the current count
$tmp = $value.$val;
         return  $tmp:
          }
          add_shortcode('CF7_counter', 'cf7dtx_counter');

          //Action performed when the mail is actually sent by CF7
          function cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter(){
          $val = get_option( CF7_COUNTER, 0) + 1; //Increment the current count
$tmp = $value.$val;
          update_option(CF7_COUNTER,  $tmp); //Update the settings with the new count
           }
           add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'cf7dtx_increment_mail_counter');
```